# Logging soap requests and responses body only Jax WS

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS for the webservices in my project. I want to log every request and response for these webservices. For the time being, I am successfully logging every request/response, however I wish to remove the header part for security reasons and keep the body, I am using in my SOAPHandler this method to write in the application log:

```
private void logToSystemOut(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogHandler.class);
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc
                .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            logger.info("Outbound message:");
        } else {
            logger.info("Inbound message:");
        }

        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        try {
            Source source = message.getSOAPPart().getContent();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                    .newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(
                    "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3"); 
            transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(baos));
            logger.info(baos.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Exception in handler: " + e);
        }
    }
```

This of course logs every request/response without distinguishing the headers and bodies. I tried using the message.getSOAPBody(), but it keeps logging null.

All recommendation are welcome.

PS: This is the return for message.getSOAPBody() is [S:Body: null]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully solved the problem used the detachnode method for the SOAP header as follows:

```
 message.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();
```

Here's a code sample of how the code becomes (notice how I test on whether the soapHeader is non-null, because otherwise it'd throw a null pointer exception):

```
    private void logToSystemOut(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogHandler.class);
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc
            .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        logger.info("Outbound message:");
    } else {
        logger.info("Inbound message:");
    }

    SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
    try {
        if(message.getSOAPHeader()!=null)
        message.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();
        Source source = message.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3"); 
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(baos));
        logger.info(baos.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Exception in handler: " + e);
    }
}}
```